# Sort date in French format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did a function for `DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#statable').DataTable();
     });
    </script>
```

My data are sorted expect that the `date`.
My column in HTML is:

```
<td><center>{{statement['Jour']}}/{{statement['Mois']}}/{{statement['Annee']}}</center></td>
```

I changed it like this:

```
<td><center>{{statement['Annee']}}/{{statement['Mois']}}/{{statement['Jour']}}</center></td>
```

it became sorted well, but I want a `French format date` and sorted.
How can I change my code?

Comment: What format is a "French format date"?

Comment: Like this:  DD/MM/YYYY and not YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the sorting now?

Comment: That should be in the question.

Comment: That date format is not “sortable” by simple string comparison, and neither can Date objects be created from it directly. So you will need to use a sorting plugin. https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ Looks like the `date-eu` plugin could already achieve what you want.

Comment: I should copy all the code of the plug-in ?